# Symfony2 - Doctrine Save entites with one to one relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, mysql-error-1064

I want to save a form that I have created but I have an error.

I have 3 entities:

```
class T {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyNameSpace\ProfileBundle\Entity\Person", cascade={"persist"})

     */
    private $information;
}

class Person {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyNameSpace\MediaBundle\Entity\Document", cascade={"persist"}))
     */
    private $photo_profile;
}

class Document
{
    private $file;
}
```

When I save my  "T" class with this code :

```
public function createAction()
{
        $entity     = new T();                        
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form    = $this->createForm(new TType(), $entity);        
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) 
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($entity);            
            $em->flush();
        }
}
```

I have this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`namespace`.`person`, CONSTRAINT `FK_3370D440809EFCB0` FOREIGN KEY (`photo_profile_id`) REFERENCES `Document` (`id`))

Any helps will be cool

Thank you for all

---

Here the code I have:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Tutor entity.
 */
public function createAction()
{       
    $entity  = new T();        
    $person = new Person();        

    $document = new Document();
    $person->setPhoto($document);

    $entity->setInformation($person);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new TType(), $entity);        
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $em->persist($entity->getInformation()->getPhoto());
        $em->persist($entity->getInformation());           
        $em->flush();

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();                       

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Index'));
    }
```

and I have this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`T`, CONSTRAINT `FK_58C6694C2EF03101` FOREIGN KEY (`information_id`) REFERENCES `Person` (`id`))

Any help please will be cool

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to save a `Person` but you did not specify the relation to Document (which must be named photo_profile) as nullable, hence this error.

Comment: you mean that I have to put : $entity->setPhotoProfile(new Document()); ?

Comment: I mean I have exactly the same error. SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (namespace.person, CONSTRAINT FK_3370D440809EFCB0 FOREIGN KEY (photo_profile_id) REFERENCES Document (id)) . I have tried to clear the cache, but it's the same

Comment: This is far better, thanks. You should try persisting the Document before setting it as photo profile. Or set a persisting cascade on the relation.

Comment: you mean that I have to persist the object P $this->persist($person);$entity->setInformation($person);$form    = $this->createForm(new PostType(), $entity);
        $form->bindRequest($request); in this order

Comment: Persist the Document, persist the Person, flush, and then persist the T. I see you already have cascades, so it is strange this doesn't already work.

Comment: and what about all the setter()? I have to setDocument() after the persisting but after the createForm() method? and if (isValid())

Comment: you have to do all this after isvalid

Comment: I have the same error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (namespace.person, CONSTRAINT FK_3370D440809EFCB0 FOREIGN KEY (photo_profile_id) REFERENCES Document (id))

Comment: I have tried to  $em->persist($entity->getInformation()->getPhoto());
        $em->persist($entity->getInformation());           
        $em->flush();

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush(); Photo and Information are saved into the database but I have the $em->persist($entity);and $em->flush();I have yet the error...

Comment: Try establishing the failing relation just after the first flush (this is weird, you shouldn't have to). Are your doctrine libraries up-to-date? Have you tried XDEBUG? Do you have a stack trace? What is the failing SQL request? What values are bound to it?

Comment: It seems that the problem is the foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue as well and cascading didn't help so I ended up just using oneToMany, manyToOne relations instead.

The alternative solution I had was to not apply the foreign key constraints in the generated SQL but that would remove my --force ability (and force me to write my own script to ignore the FK constraints), so the oneToMany solution was more elegant for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a ManyToOne relation;. I just had to :

1. persist the owner entity
2. flush
3. create the inverse and bind it
4. persist and flush again
   Then everything went normal !

Well I can't explain that but I just share my experience and maybe it will serve !